# Remove other software on installation

Tags: wix, burn

When installing my software I need to take care another msi package is uninstalled before. Is this possible? Can burn do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***MSI / Major Upgrade***: You can add entries to the [**Upgrade table**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/upgrade-table) in one or all of the MSI files you install. Then the older / other MSI will be uninstalled before (or after) your MSI is installed. This is MSI's built in ["major upgrade" feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/major-upgrades) intended to deliver upgrades for your own products, but you can uninstall any product you want that is MSI-based - even a competitive product - only if you are nuts, and do call legal first :-). Maybe see this description (related problem at least): **[Adding entries to MSI UpgradeTable to remove related products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801570/adding-entries-to-msi-upgradetable-to-remove-related-products)**.

***Burn***: Burn can run EXE files that can initiate uninstall of pre-existing MSI files, but I would never choose this approach when you can use the above built-in MSI approach instead. I am not sure if you can call **`msiexec.exe`** directly via the [**ExePackage element**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exepackage.html) of Burn, but you trigger the uninstall from within a custom made EXE file in a myriad of ways: **[Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)**. It depends what your EXE is written in. If it is managed code, maybe use the DTF method (option 6 in the linked answer). If it is C++, maybe use the MSI API Win32 functions. **See option 14** in the linked answer. I guess you can also chose to shell out to `msiexec.exe` (option 3). My advice: always go native code for deployment. Your setup must work on any machine, in any language, in any state and in any OS edition. There are many further variables. **Minimal dependencies** is the only cure.