# How to create a customized error dialog box if the application is already installed?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

How can I prompt the user that the app their trying to install is already installed?

I also removed the MaintenanceTypDlg in WixUI_InstallDir to customized my WixUI_InstallDir.

When I tried to re-install my application using the same installer, its just directly goes to the ExitDialog.
I tried putting the `<MajorUpgrade>` in Product.wxs, but there is no error message shown.

Comment: Why would you remove the maintenance dialog? Just leave it in there, problem solved? Have you checked the log files to see if there are any crashes? I suppose you could add a launch condition or hack the upgrade table to detect the same version and refuse to install. [Fine grained upgrade table control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51803320/129130).

Comment: our project does not need the maintenance dialog.

Comment: That maintenance dialog is exactly what will show up and prevent the problem you are seeing?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the details why this dialog is undesirable? For most purposes I would not recommend removing it. It is an integral part of a normal setup, and should not be viewed as optional in my opinion. It supports one of the fundamental installation modes of MSI (modify - also repair), there are many modes: `install`, `repair`, `modify`, `self-repair`, `patching`, `major upgrade`, `minor upgrade`, `resume suspended`, `etc...`. It is hard work to test all these modes, and therefore good to leave dialogs default if you can.