# how to uninstall an app while installing another app using wix installer

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I would like to uninstall an app which is in different location while installing another app with the same name. BUt the default installation directory is different for new app.

I tried couple of things but nothing is working

```
 <Property Id="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" Secure="yes" />
 <Upgrade Id="YOUR_GUID">  
 <UpgradeVersion
  Minimum="1.0.0.0" Maximum="99.0.0.0"
  Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED"
  IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no" />
</Upgrade>
```

New app wix code

```
  <Product Id="*" Name="Hector PC" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Hector Technologies" UpgradeCode="303D1BF2-E4C1-44A3-9BBC-85D61CE0F7B6">
```

Old app in different location which I need to uninstall GUID is

```
  {2EA86967-B3D3-4B2E-9DE9-28A595AF2E2E}
```

THis link gave good information but i am not able to succeed in uninstalling the first app

```
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114165/how-to-implement-wix-installer-upgrade
```

ANy light in this will be appreciable, Thanks

Comment: [Here is a link for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51803320/129130) (for now). Please skim it and see if it is relevant for you. Generally you can use the major upgrade feature to uninstall any existing MSI-installation during your new product's own MSI installation.